# Localhost does not load well

Tags: wordpress, localhost, apache2, raspberry-pi2

I create a localhost web server on my Raspberry Pi 2 using Apache2 and Wordpress.I used ethernet LAN connection.At the beginning, it worked well. Now the web page does not load well. How do I recover this error? Thank you.

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: the web page does not load properly